# How do I get userdata to execute on a custom Ubuntu 18.04 AMI?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, terraform, packer, cloud-init

I've created a custom AMI with Nginx installed using Packer based on Canonical's official Ubuntu 18.04 AMI, but I'm having trouble getting userdata to execute when deploying the AMI generated by Packer.

The following are the shell commands I'm executing in my Packer build:

`"provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": [
                "sudo apt-get update",
                "sudo apt-get upgrade -y",
                "sudo apt-get install nginx -y",
                "sudo rm -f /var/log/cloud-init.log",
                "sudo rm -f /var/log/cloud-init-output.log",
                "sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cloud/*",
                "sudo cloud-init init",
                "sudo cloud-init modules -m final"
            ]
        }
    ]`

I've tried removing the final 2 commands, but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Custom AMI how? Did you base it off an existing AMI that already has cloud-init installed (eg the official Ubuntu/Amazon Linux AMIs etc)? Or did you create it from a server ISO?

Comment: The source AMI is Canonical's official 18.04 release.  Will update the question description to reflect this.

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything with cloud-init when rebaking the AMI? You shouldn't need to do anything here so you should be able to just stop after your 3rd line and that should be fine. If it's not working then can you show what user data you're trying to execute and show the relevant cloud-init logs that fire when running an instance with your NGINX AMI?

Answer (score -1):

We tried this approach and could not get the custom scripts to run when the machine starts. I am assuming you are using Terraform/Ansible/Cloudformation to provision the resources. We moved the user data script to the terraform scripts ( can be done in Ansible too) which provisions the infrastructure and assigns the AMI. It worked for us.